# Disposing underlying MemoryStream of an XmlReader returned by a method

Tags: c#

I have the following method that returns an `XmlReader`:

```
public XmlReader RequestXML(string endpoint)
{
    using (WebClient request = this.PrepareRequest(RestMethod.GET, null))
    {
        byte[] response = request.DownloadData(this.RestUrl + endpoint);
        using (MemoryStream responseStream = new MemoryStream(response))
        {
            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(responseStream);
            return xReader;
        }
    }
}
```

But, of course, this doesn't work because the `MemoryStream` is closed before the calling code has a chance to use the `XmlReader`.  Is it possible to return an `XmlReader` and still dispose its underlying `MemoryStream`?

I've considered accepting a delegate (or `Action<XmlReader>`) as the second argument in my method to do the work within the `using`, but that design seems a bit awkward.

Also, [I can't just call `WebClient.DownloadString()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6231255/361684).

Comment: why dont u declare XmlReader xReader outside the inner using

Comment: @Dan, that won't make any difference.  The point is that `XmlReader` is consumed outside of `RequestXML`.  That being said, `MemoryStream.Dispose()` doesn't really do anything, so IMO the question is a bit moot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in doubt use `XmlReaderSettings.CloseInput` with this overload: `XmlReader.Create(Stream, XmlReaderSettings)`, like this ...

```
public XmlReader RequestXML(string endpoint)
{
    using (WebClient request = this.PrepareRequest(RestMethod.GET, null))
    {
        byte[] response = request.DownloadData(this.RestUrl + endpoint);
        MemoryStream responseStream = new MemoryStream(response);
        XmlReaderSettings xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        xmlReaderSettings.CloseInput = true;
        return XmlReader.Create(responseStream, xmlReaderSettings);
    }
}
```

This way code that calls `RequestXml` need not be responsible for disposing of the `MemoryStream`.